# How to connect three laptops

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan, ad-hoc-network

I have three laptops which i want to connect.

On one of them wireless doesn't work and on the other LAN wire doesn't work.

Is there any way by which i can use both the wireless Ad-Hoc as well as LAN wires to connect the three of them together?

All three of them works on windows 7

Comment: This is an exemplary question for SuperUser.com.

Comment: When you write "on the other" do you mean "on the other two" or "on one of the others"?

Comment: latter one.. one of the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 has a feature called [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) (ICS).

> ## Enabling ICS
>
> To enable ICS, on your host computer:
>
> 1. Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button , clicking
>      Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, clicking Network and
>      Sharing Center, and then clicking Manage network connections.
> 2. Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click
>      Properties.   If you are prompted for an administrator password or
>      confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> 3. Click the Sharing tab, and then select the Allow other network users
>      to connect through this computer’s Internet connection check box.
>
>    > ### Note
>    >
>    > The Sharing tab will not be available if you have only one network
>    >     connection.
> 4. If desired, you can also select the Allow other network users to
>      control or disable the shared Internet connection check box.
> 5. Optionally, to allow other network users to use services running on
>      your network, click Settings and select the services you want to
>      allow.
>
> When you enable ICS, your local area network (LAN) connection gets a
>   new static IP address and configuration, so you'll need to reestablish
>   any TCP/IP connections between your host computer and the other
>   network computers.
>
> To test your network and Internet connection, see if you can share
>   files between computers and make sure each computer can reach a
>   website.
>
> ## Configure TCP/IP
>
> To use ICS, make sure the local area network (LAN) connection on each
>   network computer is configured to get an IP address automatically. To
>   do this:
>
> 1. Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button , clicking
>      Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, clicking Network and
>      Sharing Center, and then clicking Manage network connections.
> 2. Right-click the LAN connection, and then click Properties.   If you
>      are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>      password or provide confirmation.
> 3. Click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or Internet Protocol
>      Version 6 (TCP/IPv6), and then click Properties.
> 4. Click Obtain an IP address automatically or Obtain an IPv6 address
>      automatically.
>
> The Internet options on your network computers should also be
>   configured for ICS. For more information, see Change Internet settings
>   for ICS (Internet Connection Sharing).
>
> Do not use ICS on a network with domain controllers, DNS servers,
>   gateways, or DHCP servers. And don't use ICS on systems configured for
>   static IP addresses.

Also, from the same page:

> ## ICS and ad hoc networks
>
> If you share your Internet connection on an ad hoc network, ICS will
>   be disabled if:
>
> - You disconnect from the ad hoc network.
> - You create a new ad hoc network without disconnecting from the ad hoc
>     network for which you enabled ICS.
> - You log off and then log back on (without disconnecting from the ad
>     hoc network).

**Note**: This article is about Windows Vista, but it should be the same way for Windows 7.

Comment: Actually i dont need to connect it to the internet, i just want to connect the three of them together for gaming

Comment: Alright. Looking at that now.

Comment: From what I see, it may actually work without you being connected to the internet. If I'm not mistaken, you're assigning the sharing to the actual network interface.. not whether it's connected to the internet or not.

Try it and comment back if it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should purchase USB wireless device to the laptop who has wireless not working. Now you will have three wireless working laptops, then you can use connectify software to create a hotspot on one of these laptops, and other laptops connect to it.

Comment: that is not a solution..

Comment: i dont need any connectify or hot spot if 3 wireless r working, ok. they can simply be connected with the help of Ad-Hoc